# PowerShell TextFile Parsing in specific format

Tags: powershell

I've been attempting to parse a series of files in a directory for a series of specific strings. So far the following has been successful in extracting the required information.

```
Param (
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
          [string] $FullyQualifiedPath
)

$OutputFile = "Example.txt"  #Adjust as needed
$FullyQualifiedPath = "C:\Location"
$Pat1 = [regex] 'Serial Number'
$Pat2 = [regex] 'Start Time'
$Pat3 = [regex] 'Error Code;'

Remove-Item "$OutputFile"
Get-ChildItem -Path "$FullyQualifiedPath" |
Get-Content  | Select-String -Pattern $Pat1,$Pat2,$Pat3 -AllMatches >>$OutputFile
```

This gives me a text file with a format similar to below:

```
2018-03-01 11:53:32> Start method command - progress; Serial number of Instrument: InstrumentA
2018-03-01 11:53:36> Main - error; An error occurred while running Vector.  The error description is: The instrument was unable to complete 
the command.
2018-03-01 11:55:37> Start method command - progress; Serial number of Instrument: InstrumentB
2018-03-01 11:55:42> Execute method - start; Method file C:\Folder\File
2018-03-01 11:55:43> Main - error; An error occurred while running Vector.  The error description is: Step cannot start while a verification 
or maintenance is outstanding.
```

However, this information is largely unusable in the state it is in.
**Is there anyway to change the output so that the file reads as below**?
Where each Error Code prints on a new line with its respective Serial Number and Start Time?

```
2018-03-01 11:53:32> Start method command - progress; Serial number of Instrument: InstrumentA | 2018-03-01 11:55:42> Execute method - start; Method file C:\Folder\File | 2018-03-01 11:53:36> Main - error; An error occurred while running Vector.  The error description is: The instrument was unable to complete the command.
2018-03-01 11:55:37> Start method command - progress; Serial number of Instrument: InstrumentB | 2018-03-01 11:55:42> Execute method - start; Method file C:\Folder\File | 2018-03-01 11:55:43> Main - error; An error occurred while running Vector.  The error description is: Step cannot start while a verification or maintenance is outstanding.
```

I'm very new to using PowerShell so apologies for my naivety in this matter.

Comment: You should provide a real life output of your `Select-String` if neccessary neutralized. It usually contains `Filename:LineNo:Line`. Are the REs once per file / in a defined order?

Comment: I have updated the examples provided in the original post to what the output file actually looks like. The output does not contain Filename:LineNo:Line as the files its parsing from don't contain that information.

It is parsing from a folder containing a large number of .TRC files. Each one is only present once as they are machine run logs.

Comment: AH, yes the (IMO superfluous) `Get-Content |` removes the file name,line. From your example data it is not clear which matches are to be combined in one output line.